# URLSession datatask return 0 bytes of data in Swift4.2/iOS12

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, ios12, swift4.2

We are accessing the PDF URL from our application and getting the PDF data. After converting our code base Swift2.3 to Swift4.2 we are getting 0 bytes of data as response. But when we open the same URL in the browser it is showing the PDF file. We are not getting any error also. In Swift2.3 code base, we are getting exact data value as valid bytes. Is there anything we need to configure in URLSession for getting the exact data bytes in Swift4.2.

//url - PDF server url value

```
let session:Foundation.URLSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration:URLSessionConfiguration.default delegate:self delegateQueue:nil)
let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler:{(data,response,error) in 
    // here data coming as 0 bytes 
})
task.resume()
```

Comment: Why are you including Foundation prefix to URLSession? Looks like you have a custom struct/class called URLSession in your project, you should avoid using Swift native structures/classes names.

Comment: I am dealing with the same issue. Did you find a solution? When I find it I'll post it here.

Comment: Same issue here, all requests return 0 bytes data but without errors

Answer (score -1):

URLSession.dataTask sometimes returns with no error but zero bytes.  My workaround is to use URLSession.downloadTask instead, and use the contents of localURL to create a Data buffer.  Incidentally, creating a String from this buffer using .utf8 encoding fails, while .ascii works fine.  I therefore suspect that encoding of the URL contents may be the issue.

Comment: this is not the right answer for the asked question.

Comment: I look forward to your “right” answer. While we’re waiting, this solution works.

Comment: This is Xcode issue, which shows the zero bytes when you see in mouse  tip pop up view. When you print it, it shows the actual bytes received.

Please see the screenshot  for more details:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15MJvmJaZFKNNTUqxwJvCn_Cy3qHk3gNy/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Yogesh, not really.  Yes, Xcode does have the issue you describe, but that is not the problem here.  Sometimes URLSession.dataTask fails to download files that browsers have no problem with.  No error is given, and printing the file shows that zero bytes were downloaded.  Using URLSession.downloadTask works fine on those files.